# Getting JSON data and adding it with list using jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am having listview in jQuery Mobile.How to populate(add) the URL JSON data to listview using jQuery Mobile.

Thanks,
Babu.

Comment: Hello Babu, welcome to SO! Can you tell me what you've already tried?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=json+to+listview+jquery+mobile&oq=json+to+listview+jqu&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l2.5981j0&sourceid=chrome&espvd=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Hi nippy I used the listview in jquerymobile static demo only will you have any code to populate data dynamically.